# admin-ajax.php blocks paypal redirection on wordpress Pinpoint Booking System

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am building a website and i am using Pinpoint booking system under wordpress 4.5. As soon as i try to make a paypal payment a loading loop starts and the redirection never happens. Chrome console reports an error:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)** on admin-ajax.php file. I am currently using PHP 5.4 on this Apache2 based server.

So far i have done the following with no success:

- I have tried to increase memory limits (both with wp_memory_limit and on php.ini)
- Disabled/Enabled/removed/reinstalled all first/third party plugins
- Everything is up to date from Wordpress Core to the plugins
- I have contacted the support team and they understand that it must be a server-side error
- I have checked my Paypal API Credentials
- I have repaired and optimized database

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE 05-05-2016**

I resolved it by migrating to another host. It definetely is a permission/server problem

Comment: Check your php/apache logs?  That's a runtime error.

Comment: Apache logs: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 500 while php-fpm logs nothing about the error...

Comment: Any other suggestions?